# Outlook: Recipient address without domain name - "Check Names" prevents sending

Tags: microsoft-outlook

The institution where I work uses a email to fax gateway reachable through an internal mail address (`test@example` in this example).

While this works for usual mail clients, Microsoft Outlook users are not able to send messages to this address. I assume because Outlook thinks that the host has to be an FQDN.

The "Check Names" popup appears and I did not find a way to skip that. Is there any way?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tried solving the problem by sending a message with VBA via CDO but the server bounced it back for an invalid address. However, we don't have a system setup like yours and the message made it past the name check because it flat out didn't do one. Try googling "VBA CDO" and try a test run. It it works, we might be able to get a workaround if your end users are OK not using the standard Outlook interface to send the messages. (I based mine on Ron de Bruin's: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm )

Comment: Thanks for your investigations! However, it should work with Outlook and like every other email. Our current workaround is to use a webmailer for sending these mails. Looks like the best would be to ask the IT staff to set up another address using an FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `File > Options > Mail`
2. Scroll down to `Send messages`
3. Locate and uncheck `Automatic name checking`

[image]

4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already, but this doesn't change anything. I think the `automatic` keyword means that it's done automatically after typing in the address? (the message shown above appears when hitting the `Send` button).

Comment: If your question stated that you already tried that I wouldn't have wasted your time with this answer. I was hoping it would be that easy. :)

Comment: Thanks man, sorry for that ;-) I did some research before posting and found that one already.

Comment: As you've been so fast and answered so nicely, I award the bounty to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Outlook insists that an address such as `test@example` is illegal, and as far as I know will never
agree to accept it. Microsoft knows best.

I believe you have two options :

1. Convince the administrator of the fax gateway to add an alias FQDN address that Outlook will accept,
2. Create another gateway server with an FQDN address that will serve as proxy to the fax gateway.

In the second case, here are some products I have found which may do the job and which I think are free (but have no personal experience with), in no particular order :

[E-MailRelay](http://emailrelay.sourceforge.net/)
[AnakogX Proxy](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/proxy.htm)
[SMTP Proxy for GMail and Windows Live Mail/Hotmail](https://smtpproxy.codeplex.com/)
[JanaServer 2](http://www.janaserver.de/start.php?lang=en&menue=home&content=jana)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Part of the question might be more, if `test@example` is valid for use with SMTP or not - so if Outlook behaves correctly or incorrectly. Finally, a way to circumvent the issue (as it doesn't help so much, who's doing it wrong) without setting up anything (besides changing a setting). So thanks for the SMTP gateway collection, but that's a bit overkill for our use-case.

Comment: Regarding the validity of `test@example`: [RFC 5321](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-2.3.5) says:
_"A domain name that is not in FQDN form is no more than a local alias.
Local aliases MUST NOT appear in any SMTP transaction"_
Given this I hope that I can convince the IT staff to set up another mail address with an FQDN.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear in the question, probably. I'm interested in answers for both: Who's right and how to fix it. I think part one is resolved. Making Outlook accept such addresses would still be nice.

Comment: Microsoft is not too obedient on standards. See also [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200807/outlook-com-hotmail-blocking-images-from-alt-port-or-non-fqdn-src).

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried everything and did not work. Finally I typed the e-mail addresses, and a semicolon ";" in between and this worked.

Comment: Even though the error message box has a title of ‘‘Check Names’’, the question suggests that this happens with a single addressee.  Are you saying that you can suppress the error by typing a semicolon ***after*** an addressee that would otherwise be flagged?